# What Stack Exchange site for game recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)'s [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) states that it is inappropriate to ask for computer game recommendations.

Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for such a question?

Comment: I doubt there'll ever be one either.

Comment: This is the ultimate subjective question, and the StackExchange Q/A format just isn't well suited for it.

Comment: @meagar Although you're perhaps generally correct there, some StackExchange sites have somewhat different rules than each other about what makes a good question. For instance, on Gardening and Landscaping, it's perfectly okay to ask for plant recommendations (but on Seasoned Advice, you can't ask for recipe recommendations).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

None currently. I had a proposal in Area51 for it but it appears to have been closed.

I recommend [Gaming's Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), there are (mostly) nice people that love to talk about games there.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean video games, there is a StackExchange site where this is on-topic. It's called [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Video games are software—so, yeah. There is a games tag. [See the help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information on what kind of game recommendation questions you can ask.

Anyway, if you also want to ask about board games, pen-and-paper RPGs, social games, night games (e.g. capture the flag) and stuff, I've begun looking for such a site—but, I haven't found one, yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange sites are a place for asking questions which have real, *objective* answers. It is not a full-on replacement for a discussion forum. Not all things that you could talk about on a forum are legitimate SE questions.

Comment: Programmers have no problems with recommending programming books. I would ask an objective question -- e.g. name titles that satisfy some conditions.

Comment: (by programmers I meant programming.stackexchange.com)